# update a module in the front page after adding new content into another page

Tags: blocks

I want to create a block on the home page which highlights the latest news from the 'news' page. I would like to add new content into the 'news' page frequently. Every time when I add a piece of new article (news), I would like the block to show the image and the title of that new article automatically.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you should be using Views.

- Create a new view
- Create a page display and configure it to output the content you want.
- Create a block display and configure it to output the content you want.
- Add the block to your homepage

Now when you add new news it will show up on both the page and the block.